# How do I trigger Python functions with arguments in a Heroku virtual instance (dyno)?

Tags: python, heroku, redis

**Context**

I'm very familiar with Swift and iOS. I'm familiar with the Python programming language and writing pure python code (by 'pure' I mean, without using modules like Django or Flask which I know nothing about). And I am completely new to server side architecture.

I've been reading a book on Redis, that uses Python and a Python Redis client (that is recommended by the guys at Redis) for it's examples.

I recently learned the basics of what 'virtualization' is, and enough about AWS to know that I should use a PaaS like Heroku rather than marshalling components together from an IaaS like AWS, as this is my first attempt at making a server backed iOS app.

**Situation**

I wanted to use Redis to store data for a simple leaderboard. I am using Redis(e) Cloud by Redis Labs, which is Redis as a service. I can connect to this from my terminal using python and the redis-cli.

The requirements for the backend are few and simple: Paging through a leaderboard with scores. And incrementing scores.

I've been reading Heroku's docs, and I drafted this simple design: iOS clients make GET requests to the Heroku dynos. The dynos will use python and the redis python client to connect to the Redis that is provided by Redis(e) cloud, and then send that data back to the iOS clients. The iOS clients can also make POST requests to the dynos, which will increment values in the Redis. I'm having the client requests waiting for the Redis data, because response time should be fast, and the data is lightweight.

What I was thinking was, I'll have 'web' dynos, which will be running a python file that has imported redis and has a variable referring to the redis connection. And that also has the function that will page data from redis and return it. As well as the increment score function which is omitted here.

```
import redis
conn = StrictRedis(host='...', port=...)

def page_leaderboard(page_number):
    ...

    return data
```

I thought, an iOS client would make a GET request containing the page number to be retrieved for the leaderboard, and the Heroku dyno will connect to the redis, and pass that data back to the client.

I understand that a Heroku Procfile containing the following would run a specific file:

```
web: python some_file.py
```

But I don't know how to trigger a specific function. I thought maybe it was something like like: web: python from some_file import some_file; page_leaderboard(x). But I'm not sure. And then I don't know how to get the page number data from the Clients GET request to pass it as argument to the function. And I don't know if the function's return statement would send that redis data back to the client.

I came across something called Flask, but people use the term 'web application' in the Flask articles and so I'm confused if I should use Flask because I'm not making a website, and my current understanding of the definition of 'web application' is "an app that is run in a web browser".

Or am I on the wrong track and this is not a good design / not how to do things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. A "web application" isn't necessarily one that runs in the browser (though perhaps usage of that term is shifting). I think of a web application as an application that's served via HTTP, which yours is.

So Flask is a great choice for how to write this in Python. Here's some code that should help you get started. (Once you're ready to run this at scale, you should look at deploying [Gunicorn](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn) in front of your Flask app.)

```
import os

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/leaderboard")
@app.route("/leaderboard/<int:page_number>")
def get_leaderboard(page_number=0):
    return "This should return the results for page {}".format(page_number)

if __name__=="__main__":
    # This line uses the PORT environment variable (set by Heroku) to
    # determine what port to host the app on. If you run this locally,
    # you should either set the PORT environment variable yourself or
    # access the app via the default port 5000. E.g.
    # curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/leaderboard/2
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000)))
```

And your `Procfile` can be just:

```
web: python some_file.py
```

As a side note, page numbers don't always work well in this type of scenario. Think through things like what happens if a new high score appears at the top of the list while a user is viewing page 1. When they then scroll to page 2, will they end up seeing a duplicate high score? (The last score on the first page has now been pushed down to be at the top of page 2.) Maybe these things are okay, but an alternative is to design an API like "tell me the 10 highest scores that are lower than X."

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help smarx :) And for clearing up my understanding of what a web application is. It's working and I am super excited! :D I did not think of that edge case for paging; thank you. I'm taking your advice.